# Failed to start the Dart CLI isolate (null). flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I have been having this error with flutter and dart. [if i try running any command or running any of my app from vs code it shows me that error, i have to delete the cache file and run a flutter upgrade before it works again. But after some while it still goes back to the error. I am using a mac](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uYZhN.jpg)

Comment: How did you solve the problem?

Comment: I have tried this https://stackoverflow.com/a/70015897/11445727