# Failed to start the Dart CLI isolate (null)

Tags: linux, flutter, dart

I installed `Flutter & Dart` on my Linux system, installation process was successful, but soon I noticed that I no more be able to open programs which placed in `/snap/` directories : sublime, android-studio and many others.

The error I got was

> Failed to start the Dart CLI isolate
> (null).

so that is what terminal says, when I'm trying to open any program placed in `/snap`, I removed `Flutter & Dart` from system but error keeps occurring. So what should I do?

Comment: btw error appears after installation Flutter. I deliberately install Dart at first and then Flutter.

Answer (score 0):

I have also faced the same error. I have tried these steps. First delete or move to trash your flutter/bin/cache folder. Then run command `flutter clean` in your project folder. Then set flutter SDK path in Android Studio -> Preferences -> Languages and Frameworks -> Flutter -> Flutter SDK path (select flutter folder in which you have installed flutter)-> Apply -> Ok

Then run `flutter pub get`

Let me know if it works for you.

Comment: Thanks, I hope that will work for somebody else, because I already have solved that problem.